# Xamarin.Forms Translate an object from Master Page to Detail page

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I would like to seek advice where to start on how to include animation in my Xamarin.Forms.
I have a contact page(master page) with Image(Photo of the person) in a list form, when tap\click on 1 of the contact, I would like to move(animation, translate) the photo to move to the Center of the device and at the same time load the Detail page(navigate).

If that possible?

thank you.

Comment: "the photo to move to the Center of the device" - what page it should be on?

Comment: Hi Yuri, Basically is to navigate from Master Page to Detail page. the Photo is located at the master page and animate the photo to the center of the device in the Detail page.

Answer (score 0):

You would use Xamarin.Forms Animation classes for this. SImilar to this

```
var animation = new Animation(callback: d => photoImage.X = d,
                              start: 0,
                              end: centerPoint - photoImage.Width,
                              easing: Easing.Linear);
```

Then you would have to call the `animation.Commit` method. But this has many options. [Custom Animations in Xamarin Forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-animations-in-xamarin-forms/) goes into more details.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply. How about the page transition? I am trying to achieve https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxZwKX7rBKREcnlpNUthd29WYjQ

Comment: You will need to create a custom renderer for the NavigationPage to control the transitions, beyond the current basic one. These also aren't as flexible as animating objects on a screen.